# IE giving ChunLoadError for angular website

Tags: internet-explorer-11, angular9

I am trying to make a website in angular9 it is loading in chrome but not loading in any version of IE. Got below Error in IE.

[image]

[image]

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Have you followed [the steps](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/14455#issuecomment-493739768) of supporting Angular 9 in IE 11?

1. Create a new tsconfig `tsconfig-es5.app.json` next to `tsconfig.app.json` with the below contents:

   ```
    {
     "extends": "./tsconfig.app.json",
     "compilerOptions": {
         "target": "es5" 
      }
    }
   ```
2. In `angular.json` add two new configuration section under the `build` and `serve` target to provide a new tsconfig:

   ```
   "build": {
     "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
     "options": {
         ...
     },
     "configurations": {
       "production": {
           ...
       },
       "es5": {
         "tsConfig": "./tsconfig-es5.app.json"
       }
     }
   },
   "serve": {
     "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
     "options": {
         ...
     },
     "configurations": {
       "production": {
        ...
       },
       "es5": {
         "browserTarget": "yourAppName:build:es5"
       }
     }
   },
   ```
3. Run the serve with this configuration using the below command:

   ```
   ng serve --configuration es5
   ```

If the issue still persists, please provide [a minimal code sample which can reproduce the issue](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Hi Yu Zhou, I had added the configurations can you please help.

Comment: Your configurations look like having no problem. The issue may be related to some syntax in other files hasn't been transpiled to es5 or some libraries haven't been transpiled. You should check the syntax error in console and try to transpile it to es5. Besides, you could provide your minimal code using some online code editor like [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/) and make sure the sample can reproduce the issue. Don't use pictures to show the code.